# Is there a terminal file-browser like ranger or nnn, which features a readonly mode?

Tags: command-line, readonly, file-browser

I am looking for a terminal file-browser like the filemanagers [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) or [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) etc, but with a readonly mode?

Comment: So in order to modify something you have to drop in a shell, the file-browser is just for navigation.

Comment: Have you tried GNU Midnight Commander?